# Parsing a String representation of XML

Tags: java, xml-parsing

From a String like

```
<TestData Identifier=\"Test\" requiredAttribute=\"Present\"></TestData> <TestData Identifier=\"Test1\" requiredAttribute=\"Present1\"></TestData> <TestData Identifier=\"Test2\" requiredAttribute=\"Present2\"></TestData> <TestData Identifier=\"Test3\" requiredAttribute=\"Present3\"></TestData>
```

whats the best way to get the values of the attributes requiredAttribute i.e (Present,Present1,Present2...)

Comment: This is probably like the most common question on this site. Do none of those **Related** questions  `------>` solve your problem?

Comment: Is it Faith Of Your Fathers that doesn't let you to type "java parse xml example" in Google?

Answer (score 1):

You can look into JAXB unmarshalling. Check out this page for more details, it should point to what you need

[http://jaxb.java.net/tutorial/section_3_1-Unmarshalling-and-Using-the-Data.html#Unmarshalling and Using the Data](http://jaxb.java.net/tutorial/section_3_1-Unmarshalling-and-Using-the-Data.html#Unmarshalling%20and%20Using%20the%20Data)

Answer (score -1):

For basic XML parsing like this, I've found NanoXML @ http://nanoxml.cyberelf.be/ to be about the easiest and mostlightweight.

Working with XML in Java send you down a long road to pain if you start using all the other libraries.

Answer (score -2):

That's not XML - but you could do it with regex *or* by converting it to XML and parsing it out. The latter is probably more expensive. It depends on what the actual test data is and your requirements for it.

Comment: can you provide me one example of how to achieve this using regex ?

Comment: It depends. What data are you trying to capture? Just the attribute?

Comment: If all you're doing is searching for the attribute, you'd match against a group of "requiredAttribute=\"([^\")\"" and capture the matches. That's horribly ugly and likely to be insufficient, but I don't know what you're trying to accomplish or with what data.

Comment: Parsing xml and stuff like it is a solved problem. Don't suggest reinventing the wheel.